# SEO Google Publisher Network

Tags: seo, google-search-console, analytics, affiliate

I'm just about to start a new business which creates niche affiliate sites. I'm curious about the impacts to me from Google of all the URLs being hosted with the same Analytics tags, Webmaster Tool tags and server IP ranges.

To benefit the most from Google's SERPs should I have each domain within seperate Analytics accounts and Webmaster Tools or is it ok for me to have all of my domains within one account.

My issue is duplicate content and the fact that I am building a publisher network and I'm not sure how much Google likes them.

I'm notoriously bad at searching and as such havent found what I'm looking for yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think Google may be capable of knowing all websites in one Webmaster Tools account have connections each other. By logic, one account means it's same webmaster for these websites.

Moreover, as you create a websites network, the day when Google would apply a sanction to one of your websites, it will be easy to identify your websites network. It will be more easy if your websites are linked each other.

Otherwise, duplicate content is bad for SEO, you need to avoid it if you don't want to be blacklisted by Google.

My advice:

- Use separate Google accounts (webmaster tools, analytics)
- Try to not link too much your websites each other (in the network)
- Avoid duplicate content
- Don't use Black Hat technics (build websites network to put affialite links is considered as Black Hat technics)
- Try to make things good

If you use Black Hat technics with duplicate content and same Google account for your websites, I don't think Google will appreciate your network longer.